Argo Workflow: Permission issue with `system:serviceaccount:default:default`
My cron workflows are running fine, but at the end I am getting the following error that I am investigating:
Error (exit code 1): pods "argo-cron-test-1720194660-run-script-2326994143" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot patch resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
I investigated the following settings:
kubectl get rolebindings -n argo

NAME                       ROLE                            AGE
argo-binding               Role/argo-role                  12d
agent-default              Role/agent                      12d
artifactgc-default         Role/artifactgc                 12d
executor-default           Role/executor                   12d
github.com                 Role/submit-workflow-template   12d
pod-manager-default        Role/pod-manager                12d
workflow-manager-default   Role/workflow-manager           12d

kubectl get serviceaccounts -n argo
NAME          SECRETS   AGE
default       0         12d
argo          0         12d
argo-server   0         12d
github.com    0         12d
ali@v141:~/ali$ kubectl describe rolebinding agent-default -n argo
Name:         agent-default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  Role
  Name:  agent
Subjects:
  Kind            Name     Namespace
  ----            ----     ---------
  ServiceAccount  default

kubectl describe rolebinding executor-default -n argo
Name:         executor-default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  Role
  Name:  executor
Subjects:
  Kind            Name     Namespace
  ----            ----     ---------
  ServiceAccount  default

kubectl describe role executor -n argo
Name:         executor
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  workflows.argoproj.io/description: Recomended minimum permissions for the `emissary` executor.
PolicyRule:
  Resources                        Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------                        -----------------  --------------  -----
  workflowtaskresults.argoproj.io  []                 []              [create patch]


The default service account seems to have the required create patch permissions through role binding.
Why am I getting the error?

isn't the problem with the service account default in the default namespace? You're showing us the default service account in the argo namespace.

This is a fresh argo workflow installation with a default QuickStart sample hello world. workflow. It supposed to work with no issues.

The service account is attempting to patch pods in the default namespace, but it only has patch permissions for the argo namespace. To fix this, run the workflow in the argo namespace or add a new Role and RoleBinding to the default service account.
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-patcher
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["patch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-patcher-binding
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: pod-patcher
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

